# EditText blocks when calling clearSpans

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am trying to implement a simple kind of syntax highlighting in Android using EditText and setSpan. The syntax-highlighting methods are called from within a TextWatcher's afterTextChanged. In order to have a fresh start, I want to clear all spans at the beginning. Yet, I can only enter one character. After that, the app does not call afterTextChanged anymore and seems to be stuck.

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val editor: EditText = findViewById(R.id.sourceEditText)!!

        editor.addTextChangedListener(MyTextWatcher())
    }

    class MyTextWatcher(): TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "afterTextChanged");
            s.clearSpans()
            Log.d("MainActivity", "afterTextChanged end")
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "beforeTextChanged")
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onTextChanged")
        }
    }
}
```

The log's output after entering two characters ([edit] only the first of which is shown) is

```
2019-09-16 17:35:28.418 6231-6231/at.searles.sourceeditor D/MainActivity: beforeTextChanged
2019-09-16 17:35:28.419 6231-6231/at.searles.sourceeditor D/MainActivity: onTextChanged
2019-09-16 17:35:28.431 6231-6231/at.searles.sourceeditor D/MainActivity: afterTextChanged
2019-09-16 17:35:28.433 6231-6231/at.searles.sourceeditor D/MainActivity: afterTextChanged end
```

and the app is stuck.

I am testing on the emulator with API 24/Android 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and instead of clear all spans you need to remove only the types of spans that you added:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    lateinit var editor: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editor = findViewById(R.id.sourceEditText)!!
        editor.addTextChangedListener(MyTextWatcher())
    }

    inner class MyTextWatcher() : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            editor.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            val spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length, YourHighlightSpan::class.java)
            for (sp in spans) {
                s.removeSpan(sp)
            }
            editor.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that editable actually contains a lot of spans from EditText and the TextWatcher, so removing these is obviously a mistake. What I don't understand in your answer is why you temporarily remove the listener.

Comment: Look at [afterTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)).  Because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.